# OpenCV find contour of this image to crop and rotate

Tags: opencv, contour

I'm trying to detect the contour of this image in order to crop it in openCV.

I've come up with working code, however, if there is some slight background on the image, it will fail.

Image processing:

[image]

Detect boundaries (blue dots):

[image]

Crop/rotate:

[image]

However, with an image like this, with some background light, it wouldn't work:

[image]

preprocess:

[image]

Boundaries detection:

[image]

```
def preProcessing(img):
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    adaptive_thresold1 = 31
    adaptive_thresold2 = 7

    blur = cv2.blur(imgGray, (3, 3))
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,adaptive_thresold1,adaptive_thresold2)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

    stackedImages = hp.stackImages(0.1,([img,thresh, close],[img,thresh, close]))
    cv2.imshow("WorkFlow", stackedImages)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
    return thresh


def getContours(img):
    biggest = np.array([])
    maxArea = 0
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area>5000:
            print (area)
            
            #cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*peri,True)
            
            if area >maxArea and len(approx) == 4:
                biggest = approx
                maxArea = area
                print ("ok")
                
    print (biggest)
    out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(out, biggest, -1, (255, 0, 0), 50)

    stackedImages = hp.stackImages(0.1,([img,out],[img,out]))
    cv2.imshow("WorkFlow", stackedImages)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    return biggest
```

Any suggestion to make this code more reliable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using adaptive thresholding, try using [Otsu's thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).

Change this line

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,adaptive_thresold1,adaptive_thresold2)
```

in your code to -

```
retval_blue, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This worked for me in the image.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that OTSU method, that will help a lot